# Typeerror at/10 my_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: django, django-models, bootstrap-4, django-templates, django-views

I am getting a typeerror my_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

views.py:

```
 def my_view(request):
        prod = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=1)
        context = {
            'prod': prod,
        }
        return render(request, 'title.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
         urlpatterns = [
            path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
            path('<int:pk>', views.my_view, name='my_view'),
            path('', views.index),

    ]
```

My template when I make a search:

```
          {% if results.products %}
             {% for product in results.products %}
             <div class="col-sm-{% column_width results.products %} pb-5"> 
                         <div class="card">
                       <div class="card-header bg-default" align="center">
                            <b>{{product.title}}</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="{% url 'my_view' product.id %}">{{ 
                             product.Author }}</a>
                            <p>{{ product.description|striptags }}</p>
                            <h6 class="btn btn-primary btn-large"> 
                                         {{product.price}}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
```

My template to render when making a click on one of the search:

```
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h2>{{ prod.title }}</h2>
                   <p>{{ prod.description }}</p>
                   <h6 class="btn btn-primary btn-large">{{judi.price}}</h6>
                   <h6 style="float: right;">{{judi.modified_date}}</h6>
              </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your 
 view that, a parameter named `pk` will come alongside the request. 
You need to change:

`def my_view(request):`

with
`def my_view(request, pk)`

Furthermore, in your `urls.py` you need to give a path to your view, your current path lacks a path string. You need to replace:

`path('<int:pk>', views.my_view, name='my_view')`  with:

`path('my_view/<int:pk>', views.my_view, name='my_view')`

Also in your template replace:

`<a href="{% url 'my_view' product.id %}">` with

`<a href="{% url 'my_view' pk=product.id %}">`

Comment: just seen another error and updated the answer. check it please

Comment: with what url are you trying to go to your view?

Comment: {% url  'my_view' product.id %}

Comment: I changed my-view to my_view re-check my answer.